# Generate "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY" With Spring JPA for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to get Spring-Data-JPA to generate PRIMARY KEY column with `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`.

```
class SomeClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private ID id;
    ...
}
```

The result obtained with `javax.persistence.*` library is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.sometable
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sometable_id_seq'::regclass),
    ...
    CONSTRAINT sometable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ...
);
```

However, the ideal code would be:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.sometable (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
    ...
);
```

Is there a directive to tell Spring Data to generate `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` with **PostgreSQL**?

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible. Have tested with columnDefinition, and it either produces an exception or an invalid DDL. Have a nice day :)